# Give users some control to the company pages slider

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The new [Careers 2.0 Company Pages](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products/company-pages) is a great idea and a great feature and opportunity for companies to showcase their work environment. In that page we see a slider (that of the *"Who uses Careers 2.0 Company Pages?"* section) that automatically switches to the next two companies after a few seconds, a common behavior of sliders. However, there is something very important that the slider lacks: control.

I find it very inconvenient to just wait for the next two companies to show. I'm pretty sure that would also be the case for others using that page. What I want to have is a simple next/previous control or those clickable bullet thingies that enables us to choose which slide is to be shown.

I think this would be a very good improvement to the usability of the page, therefore also improving user experience.

---

**ADDITIONAL 1:** "Pausing" the slider is not that of a problem for it automatically halts to the current slide whenever the slider is hovered.

**ADDITIONAL 2:** This is mostly in response to @djechlin's first comment (thank you for pointing that out). By adding control to the slider, we enable the slider to serve two types of audiences at the same time: those who want control and those who are willing to wait for the next slide to show. We're missing something that control-freaks (and the impatient) want. By giving them the control, we can therefore serve their needs without sacrificing the kind of usability that the other type of users need.

Comment: Maybe not, forcing the user to heed attention for a couple seconds before next-ing through is not necessarily bad UX.

Comment: @djechlin Careers 2.0 is made with programmers as the primary audience, and a site must consider what its audience needs. Programmers, in our very nature, wants control. And control is a feature that *that* slider needs.

Comment: The review queues limit even on skips, you must wait 2 days before answering your own question, 10 minutes before accepting your own answer, etc.  But the review queue is most relevant.  It does indeed *force* a pause.